# POSTing with Flash

Tags: flash, post

I've been trying to get the following code to work:

```
var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/script.php");
var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
```

scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
    scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);

```
function write(write_to_file) {      
scriptVars.req = "testing testing testing";

scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;
```

scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
    }

```
function handleLoadSuccessful($evt:Event):void
{
```

trace("Message sent.");

```
}
```

function handleLoadError($evt:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
     trace("Message failed.");
    }

---

Strangely enough, it POSTs correctly from Flash.. but when I upload to my web server it does not... Any ideas?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can check your variables send to the remote url using web debuggers(charles, fiddler, etc).It can help you to see what are the variables are sending.
2. Also don't forget to check you are using **$_POST** to receive the data

It is important to receive the data in the same method you are using or common method like $_REQUEST.

I guess this is the problem in your case.